# Why does Visual Studio show the option /PGD in the linker command line when I use just the linker option /LTCG?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

If you build a project in `Release` mode containing just a `.cpp` file with `int main() {}`, you'll see in `Configuration Properties > Linker > Command Line` the option `/PGD:"C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\solution name\Release\project name.pgd"`, as if the linker should create a data base file for a profiled-guided optimization for this project.

But that clearly is **not** the case, as the `/LTCG` option used by the linker in a release build is just `/LTCG` and not `/LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT`. To corroborate this, one can check the absence of any `.pgd` file in the `Release` directory mentioned above.

Why then, does Visual Studio have this option (/PGD) in the project's command line?

P.S. I'm using VS2017 for this simulation, but I believe the result should be the same in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe [this MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pgd-specify-database-for-profile-guided-optimizations) article can be of help.

Comment: It more or less confirms what I said. `When using /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT, use /PGD to specify a nondefault name or location for the .pgd file.`

Comment: This option *always* has a value, the default is $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pgd.  Producing the path you showed.  Changing the setting is rarely necessary.  It is not clear why you don't like the default.

Comment: Please give the VS version number.

Comment: @HansPassant That seems to be the answer. I didn't realize the default was  $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pgd. Thanks.

Comment: @tambre VS2017 version 15.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Visual Studio project has the [`/PGD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pgd-specify-database-for-profile-guided-optimizations) option set by default with a default path of `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pgd`. This setting has no effect unless you explicitly enable PGO using [`/LTCG:PG*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation) options.